# What else do the gods have besides avatars? Do the gods have something like manifestations and expansions of their being?

Tags: gods

Something like superior forms or true forms that exist in a higher level of reality and what we see or know in reality does not represent the true form of the gods, being their true form absolutely transcendent and incomprehensible.

Comment: There are various manifestations and expansion of God. For example in case of Lord Vishnu he manifests in some Swyambhu idols (self formed) and Shaligrama stones etc.. He manifests also in forms like Vasudeva, Sankarshana, Pradyumna, Aniruddha (4 vyuha forms). In case of Lord Shiva he manifests as Swayambhu Linga in various places and also as Banalingas.. His expansion forms are considered as forms of Brahma, Vishnu, Rudra, Maheshwara and Sadashiva (Pancha Brahman).. Also he manifests as this visible world in his Ashtamurti (Eight forms) forms...

Comment: Not clear are the difference between avatar and manifestation...isn't an avatar a manifestation? "true form being absolutely transcendent and incomprehensible" may apply to Brahman, but not to the 'gods' - the devas.